# When does multi-particle entanglement break?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Let's say we entangle four electrons based on their spin.

Now, let's say we measure the spin of electron A along the z-axis (up/down), and we observe a spin of 'up'. My understanding is that this means that the remaining three electrons would need to have some combination of spin which adds up to 'down'.

Next, we measure the spin of a second electron, but along the x-axis (left/right), and say we observe 'right'.

My question is, what does this mean for the up/down spin of the entangled system?

I'm thinking since it can't be that the remaining two electrons add up to a 'down' spin, it must be that the second electron we measured also still has a state for up/down spin that has not been observed yet. But that would also imply that it's still entangled with the other electrons; this is where I'm confused, cause it was my understanding that a measurement would break entanglement. Is that correct, or no? What actually breaks the entanglement in this case?

Hope the question makes sense, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, let's say we measure the spin of electron A along the z-axis (up/down), and we observe a spin of 'up'. My understanding is that this means that the remaining three electrons would need to have some combination of spin which adds up to 'down'.

No, not necessarily. You need to specify exactly *how* you entangle together the spins - that is, you need to specify the exact four-spin wavefunction. There are many states of four entangled spins for which $\sum_i \langle S_i^z \rangle \neq 0$.

It sounds like you're probably assuming that the four spins are entangled in the singlet state. But it turns out that for four spin-1/2's, there are actually two orthogonal singlet states, so this still doesn't uniquely specify the wavefunction.

As soon as you measure the spin of electron A, you put it into a pure state that is not entangled with the other spins - that is, you break the entanglement. After that, no subsequent measurements (or unitary operations) that you apply to any of the other three spins will subsequently change anything about electron A - it's doing its own thing from now on.

But your question doesn't contain enough information to say anything more detailed than that, unless you specify an explicit wavefunction for the four spin-1/2's.

One simple initial state is that electrons A and B are entangled into a singlet pair, and separately electrons C and D are as well. In this case, particles C and D simply remain in an entangled singlet throughout; none of the measurements of electrons A or B ever affect their state at all.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Okay, let's assume the initial angular momentum was zero at the time of entanglement. To be honest I'm trying to learn this stuff conceptually, but I wouldn't know exactly how to express the wave function mathematically. Would you mind supposing one which nets to zero angular momentum?

Comment: @Leo There are two different states of four spins that have zero total angular momentum. Neither one of them is very easy to write down explicitly. You’d need to specify which one you’re starting from; I think the final answer would probably depend on which one. I think you’d need to sit down and work out a pretty nontrivial calculation in order to find the final state of the two unmeasured electrons.

Comment: @Leo See the paragraph I added to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! Is there a way to entangle all four so that they are all entangled with one another rather than two singlet pairs? That's a conceptual question, not asking for the math / wave function, just if it's possible

Comment: @Leo Yes, I believe that for a generic state in the 2D singlet manifold, all four electrons will be entangled together.

Comment: The problem with electron A is that you don't know the direction of the spin in advance. If you measure the spin (its magnetic dipole), you will falsify its exact orientation and you will only get the projection of the real spin onto the measured direction. You will only know if the real spin has a positive orientation or a negative one. In doing so, you will not only destroy the orientation of the first electron, but also its entanglement with the other three. The new entaglement of the three remaining electrons therefore changes compared to the initial state. >>>

Comment: <<< In my opinion, you can theoretically read out Qbits in two ways. The first is impossible in any case: the measuring device is a small magnet and the electron is the large magnet. So the small magnet is influenced and rotated without destroying the qbit. Does not exist in nature. >>>

Comment: <<< The second possibility is theoretically to take into account the strength of the measurement (do I hit the orientation direction). By measuring the qubit repeatedly with the progressive pre-orientation of the measuring device in the actual spin direction of the electron to be measured, I get my result. And do not destroy the qubit after x attempts.